# How do I delete the untouchable grammerly from my mac?

Tags: mac

It cannot be deleted because it constantly says it is still open. I tried damaging it by compressing it twice, and now it's 0 bytes and cannot be opened. But still cannot be deleted because it says it's open.

Comment: "damaging it by compressing it twice" - not sure how you thought this would help - you saved a compressed version next to the uncompressed version, didn't change anything. Grammarly says you should just be able to delete it. Reboot & try again.

Comment: Did you click on the Grammarly button in the menu bar and selected Quit? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)